# Find a string if it is present in another string

Tags: c++, string

How can I find if a string is present in another string, not using a string comparison function but by iterating over each character and testing the equality in C++?

```
string one="hello world"; // Search *in* this string
string two="wor";         // Search *for* this string
```

Comment: Please try to edit your question so it will be more clear.. right now it's difficult to understand what you are asking..

Comment: If you "do the needful" and edit your question you will probably get more replies.

Comment: I agree with @NicoMayer -- this looks like homework.  If so, please be sure to always indicate this by adding the [tag:homework] tag. Also, you should attempt to solve the problem and show the progress that you've made. We're happy to help you, but we don't want to just do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a homework ^^

```
int find(string one, string two){
    int a, b;
    for(int c = 0; c + two.length() < one.length(); c++){
        a = 0;
        b = c;
        while(a < two.length() && one[b++] == two[a++]);
        if(a == two.length())return c;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: If you think it's homework you should avoid posting a complete answer.